# Difference between fastboot and recoverymode in android

Tags: android, recovery, rom, fastboot

I just wants to know the difference between fastboot and recovery modes in android device.

So far my understanding I thought that

Recovery mode : contains a small Linux image, having some simple User interface with few recovery options.

fastboot mode : Once the phone is into fastboot mode we can install recovery images.

can you please confirm whether my understanding is correct or not and please tell me when to use which one or combination of these two .

Comment: Fastboot is not available on all devices whereas recovery is present in all devices ...
Refer this :
Fastboot
http://www.androidcentral.com/android-z-what-fastboot
vs 
Recovery
http://www.androidcentral.com/what-recovery-android-z
I hope you will get the answer. :)

Comment: As this is not a programming question, it's not really appropriate for stackoverflow. The Android Enthusiasts site, http://android.stackexchange.com/, would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- Recovery mode is small Linux operating system where you can factory reset your device or update your device with vendors images.
- Fastboot it's a tool which comes with the android sdk and you can use it to re-flash partitions of your device. Because fastboot starts before android and even when android isn't installed you can use it as an alternative of recovery mode in case recovery mode partition is corrupted. Every phone usually has fastboot,but some vendors choose to replace fastboot with their tool. Like samsung, instead of fastboot it has Odin.

Now, fastboot is more useful because you can use it as a recovery method when you don't have another recovery method.

Comment: So "Odin Mode" is not compatible with the `fastboot` command, and there is nothing in the Samsung phone that is compatible with it?

Answer (score 21):

Android device has 3 important partitions - Boot loader, Recovery, Android ROM. Boot loader loads first and decides the next partition to be loaded which is usually the Android ROM. Recovery is the mode that is used by device to install updates to Android ROM partition. It is also used while factory resetting the phone. The recovery that comes by default usually has less options and that is why custom recovery modules are available.

Fastboot on the other hand is a protocol that can be used to connect to the device from a computer over USB and issue updates to the partitions of the device. For example, while I'm in fastboot I can update by recovery partition.